# Laravel attach issue

Tags: laravel, pivot

I'm going to attach a specific `present` item with various pivot values to a single `order`. I'm looking around for something like :

```
$order->presents()->attach(1,[
    ['price' => '2400, 'qty' => 2],
    ['price => '1000, 'qty' => 4]
  ]);
```

of course its not a valid code.i can attach items one by one:

```
$order->presents()->attach(1,['price' => '2400, 'qty' => 2]);

$order->presents()->attach(1,['price => '1000, 'qty' => 4]);
```

but i think there should be a better way, can anyone let me know how may i do a  bunch attach?

Answer (score 0):

Lookin at the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#inserting-many-to-many-relationships) I can see you almost got the solution.

Referring to the documentation you should use an array like `array(id => [values])`. In your case:

```
$order->presents()->attach([
    1 => [
        'price' => 2400,
        'qty' => 2
    ],
    ....
]);
```

This code has not been tested.

**Edit**

When you check the `attach()` function in the deep dungeons of the Laravel framework can see it also accepts a Model, Collection or integer. When you look further you can see it (maybe) also accepts an array of ID's.

```
/**
 * Attach a model to the parent.
 *
 * @param  mixed  $id
 * @param  array  $attributes
 * @param  bool   $touch
 * @return void
 */
public function attach($id, array $attributes = [], $touch = true)
{
    if ($id instanceof Model) {
        $id = $id->getKey();
    }

    if ($id instanceof Collection) {
        $id = $id->modelKeys();
    }

    $query = $this->newPivotStatement();

    $query->insert($this->createAttachRecords((array) $id, $attributes));

    if ($touch) {
        $this->touchIfTouching();
    }
}
```

Don't know if it works, but try:

```
$order->presents()->attach([1, 1], [[
            'price' => 2400,
            'qty' => 2
        ], [
            'price' => 1337,
            'qty' => 420
        ]
    ]
]);
```

Comment: Just note that duplicate array key is not valid in PHP. i generate (attach method) data with a `foreach` loop , so there is no way to create an array like what you've presented in answer with `foreach`

Comment: You are right! Did not notice you wanted to attach the same resource twice. I'll do some more research and come up with a new answer when I found one.

Comment: thanks for reply but  doesn't work: `ErrorException in helpers.php line 747: preg_replace(): Parameter mismatch, pattern is a string while replacement is an array`

Comment: `attach` method doesn't accept a multidimensional array as `$attribute` .probably i should send a PR or use a simple bare query

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
$order->presents()->attach([
1 => ['count' => 3, 'price' => '2400, 'qty' => 2],
2 => ['count' => 4, 'price' => '2400, 'qty' => 2]
]);
```